# api call to server returns empty array on iOS but not android

Tags: react-native, axios, react-native-ios

Guys I need your help.

I'm using react native v 0.63 to build a usual app. Nothing too crazy.

The weird thing which is happening is that my axios call to our own server is returning empty array in iOS simulator which is not correct! I already have tested it on android device, and data is coming as expected with no issue (an array of objects), which means there should not be any problem with the code.

So what is the reason then?

I am using iOS simulator 5s.

Here is the code:

```
      const selectedChildId = useSelector((state) => state.user.selectedChildId);
      const request = () => {
       const url = `api/v1/tasks/task-category/?child=${selectedChildId}`;
       if (selectedChildId) {
        setLoading(true);
         Axios.get(url)
          .then(({ data }) => {
             console.warn('data', data); --> in iOS simulator result is: 'data []' which is wrong!
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.warn('err', error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    request();
  }, [selectedChildId]);

  );
```

Comment: Did you define your baseUrl in axios?

Comment: Yes. you know, there are a lot of axios calls which are working correctly on both devices, but for this one, I still don't know what's wrong.@chrisby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out issue was because of **axios header**. One needed field in header was missing, which happened to cause the problem in iOS. In android though, the default value was being set, and therefore everything was working just fine.